# Trouble with generic collections in Scala

Tags: generics, scala, collections, scala-collections

I'm puzzled as to how to solve this in Scala. In Java I'd give up on generics or use casts, but Scala is more strict than that. Here's what I have.

1. An abstract base class `Factory[+F <: Factory[F]]` and some concrete implementations irrelevant here. This is covariant. This class has a method that creates Products - see next point.
2. An abstract base class `Product[+F <: Factory[F]]` that represents a product of the factory. These are also covariant and read-only. Any specific factory produces exactly one type of  product (i.e. there aren't multiple different subtypes - FooFactory produces FooProduct, BarFactory produces BarProduct, etc.)
3. I must have a collection of factories that contains the concrete instances (Capt. Obvious speaking here). Presently this is `Iterable[Factory[_]]`. This is the first part of trouble. Scala seems to understand `_` here as `Any`, disregarding the constraint `F <: Factory[F]` on the type itself.
4. I have an aggregated factory method that asks each factory to produce its product given same arguments. The result is a Map of factories to their products, presently coded as `Map[Factory[_],Product[_]]` and also tried `Map[Factory[_],Product[Factory[_]]]`. This is another part where I get in trouble. The first `_` is unlinked from the second `_` and both seem to be implied as `Any`.

What I can't do is create that map. It may or not be important, but I do it (and have to do it) by using yet another method made to look like a syntax construct. It comes from a trait and:

1. Calls a declared method (call it `gather[B](fun: A => B): Map[A,B]` here, not implemented in the trait itself and generically typed) that gets the collection of factories. The actual factory type is generic and unknown.
2. Iterates over that generic collection and executes a function passed to it. This function is what actually calls the factory method.
3. Returns an immutable `Map` of F to P

The compiler trouble in not in 'gather' method but in the code that calls it. I can't cast its result to `Map[Factory[_],Product[_]]` because _ does not conform to `F <: Factory[F]` in either place... I'd be more than happy to use a base type for `_`, but that'd be `Factory[Factory[Factory[Factory......(infinitely many times)]]]]]]....` and I don't know what to do.

Please help!

Learner

Comment: Could you post some example code?

Comment: If you could just post the type signatures of the classes and methods involved in this, it would help a lot. For instance, what's the type signature of the method mentioned on 4?

Answer (score 5):

Most of the time, using `_` in types is the wrong thing to do unless you know what you are doing. And if you don't understand existential types, then you most certainly don't know what you are doing. It is not that Scala thinks `_` is `Any`, it is that it *knows* `_` can stand for anything -- be it `Any`, `Nothing` or anything in between.

To sum it up, `Iterable[Factory[_]]` means `Iterable[Factory[T]] forSome { type T }`. You can write it explicitly as `Iterable[Factory[T]] forSome { type T <: Factory[T] }` to get the constrains you want, just as you can write it as `Map[Factory[T], Product[T]] forSome { type T <: Factory[T] }`.

I'm not sure, though, if that really is what you need. Your questions is focusing on how you are trying to solve the problem, instead of focusing on how to solve the problem. It might be, for instance, that it would be better to use the following instead of generics:

```
abstract class Factory {
    type T <: Factory
}
```

Comment: The reason why I am saying "Any" is because Scala compiler tells me that it found "Any" but requires X <: ...[X].

Comment: Also, I do not want to use _ ... I'd like not to. The problem I have is expressing the "base" type of Foo[T <: Foo[T]]? I'd have to use that in my maps, for both keys (factories) and values (products). And, don't tell me "Any" ...  I need Foo members available there...

Comment: Sorry, I meant Foo[+T <: Foo[T]] - needs to be covariant.

Comment: @Learner That `Any` is the result of Scala trying to infer the type according to the boundaries, etc. As for the rest of the comments, sorry, but I don't understand what you are saying.

Comment: Forget about a map for now. Say there is a simple class Value[V](val value: V). Suppose that you also have an abstract class Foo[+T <: Foo[T]]. Tell me what should be the type parameter V for the Value class such that a variable of that Value[V] type can hold ANY POSSIBLE instance of a class extending Foo (but no classes that do not extend Foo)?

Comment: @Learner `class Value[V <: Foo[V]](val value: V)` does it.

Comment: @Learner Or, if you want a `var` that can be reassigned to any _other_ `Foo`, then this works: `class Value2(var value: Foo[T] forSome { type T <: Foo[T] })`. In this case, however, you will never be able to recover the information about `T`.

Comment: I'm find not being able to recover info from specific T at this level. In other words, if the code isn't aware of the specific type, it doesn't need it either.

Comment: However, you are changing the Value class to fit your purpose and, thus, limiting it to Foo. Consider Value class being third party such that you can't change it. Then what?

Comment: @Learner Then I don't understand the problem. If you can't change `Value`, how do you expect to restrict what it can contain?

Comment: What I mean is that I can't change the Value class, nor I would want to. That class is general purpose and should accept any type as its type parameter.

Answer (score 2):

Pardon me if my Scala a bit rusty. I'm writing out of general OOP-and-generics sense.

It is not clear why `Factory` or `Product` need to be generics at all, much mess with covariance. Whether it is actually needed or not, it is necessary and sufficient to have a simple non-generic class `FactoryBase`, of which all `Factory` classes ultimately inherit. You stick that into an `Iterable[FactoryBase]`.

It is also not clear why a `Product` type contains any information about a `Factory`. The opposite would have more sense, if you indeed need that information. A `Factory` produces a `Product`, hence, knows about it, so this knowledge *might* be reflected in the type. Then again, it might not.

Just in case you need genericity, covariance and full type information, you can use such hierarchies:

```
FactoryBase
   Factory[+F <: Factory[F,P], +P <: Product[F,P]] <: FactoryBase
      FooFactory <: Factory[FooFactory, FooProduct]
ProductBase
   Product[+F <: Factory[F,P], +P <: Product[F,P]] <: ProductBase
      FooProduct <: Product[FooFactory, FooProduct]
```

Feel free to omit any type parameters you don't need.

It is also not clear why you need a map that maps factories to products. Maps usually map things like *names* to entities. That is, given a name, find an *existing* entity with that name. Factories *create* new out of thin air. In any case, if you indeed need such a map, you can use `Map[FactoryBase, ProductBase]`. This does not provide static guarantee that a `FooFactory` maps to a `FooProduct` and not to a `BarProduct`, but a `Map` cannot provide that. Then again, you can just stick a `Product` inside its respective `Factory`. You already know the mapping at compile time, there's no need for a run-time `Map`. On the `n`th hand, a product need not be associated with any factory after it is produced.

Perhaps I am misunderstanding you completely and you need to elaborate a lot on your design. As such its purpose and architecture is not clear at all.

Comment: I'm half of a mind to +1 you on the criticism of the question alone. :-)

Comment: Well, I am hiding a part of the implementation here (and am renaming classes), but among other reasons, products are able to return the factories that created them. To return a properly typed factory, the product will have to have the factory type as its type parameter. Similar works the other way. 

Furthermore, maps do not map just "names" and not only to "entities". That is a very narrow view of the world.

Comment: Also, the reason for covariance is that in my case, the class hierarchy of products must mirror and is related to the class hierarchy of the factories, and it is deeper than just one level. A particular sub-factory F2 of super-factory F1 will always produce products P2 that are subclasses of P1 produced by F1.

Comment: I could do use two type args for factories and products, but that does not answer my question at all, and that is the Map question. Think of it this way ...

Comment: Factories have only a few instances ... essentially they are singletons per concrete type. They create objects given some parameters (that I can't talk about). And every time I will need products from all factories. I could return other structures (e.g. a simple list or array of products), but I'd loose on the functionality that I truly need - map functionality (look up the product by the factory).

Comment: Thus, every (set of) call(s) to the set of factories will produce a new and different set (map) of results that needs to be available for some time later without recreating the products or invoking factories lazily - these must be enumerable immediately following the call.

Comment: As I asked in my comment to another answer below, my main problem is what is the root/base type of the Foo[+T <: Foo[T]] type hierarchy? That is what I'd need for Map type parameters, one for the factories (map keys) and another for products (map values). I know Foo[_] is not that, but I don't know of a better answer.

Comment: I do not fully understand existential types, but I also don't see how they can help me at the map level. The truth is that there will be multiple different key types and multiple different value types. I need that base I mentioned above. Given covariance, base should do the trick if such a thing exists in Scala. As I said, in Java, I could, in worst case, use "raw type" (just "Foo", not "Foo<?>") to get around the problem, but that can't be done in Scala.

Is this a shortcoming of the language or something I am missing?

Comment: @Learner I'm flexible. If you want covariance, my example has that, and the hierarchy can be extended deeper. If you want a map, there's a map too. I'm still not sure why you need them. Not everything need be encoded on the type level. Anyway, this is well beyond simple question about Scala type system. The 3-level structure of this site is not very well suited for discussing deep and intricate things.

Comment: Ok I think I understand why you need a map. I might be able to write another answer in a couple of hours, when I get back to a real keyboard (only have a phone right now) so don't give up.

Comment: @Learner Please, do not expand your question in comments to the answers. Edit _the question_, and put the extra information there. Then you can just post a comment saying "Here, I added more information to the question.  Please look at it."

Comment: I didn't expand the question. I just identified the root of what I believe is the problem.

Comment: @Learner I meant "expand" in the sense of adding more information.

Comment: I had to go with with a similar design, creating two new base classes for Factory and Product as you did here because I still have found no way to indicate the common superclass without that. That's a pitty since it forces me to declare stuff multiple times  (classes, methods)... Scala should have a way to identify the base/root of the class hierarchy of covariant types such as Foo[+T <: Foo[T]]. For Foo[+T <: Bar] that is Foo[Bar], but for Foo[+T <: Foo[T]] there seems to be no answer...

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure that I understand your problem, but try to use something like :

```
gather[A : Factory, B : Factory](fun: A => B): Map[A,B]
```

Comment: gather function works fine and is exactly as shown short of that B is a product, not a factory.

Answer (score 1):

Adding another answer instead of editing the old one.

I will talk not necessarily in terms of Scala type system, as the ideas here are applicable to many different languages.

First, before talking about maps, let me show how to make a deeper parallel hierarchies. It's really easy, just insert another level:

```
FactoryBase
   Factory[+F <: Factory[F,P], +P <: Product[F,P]] <: FactoryBase
      SomeFactoryGroup[+F <: SomeFactoryGroup[F,P], +P <: SomeProductGroup[F,P]] <: Factory[SomeFactoryGroup, SomeProductGroup]
        FooFactory <: SomeFactoryGroup[FooFactory, FooProduct]
ProductBase
   Product[+F <: Factory[F,P], +P <: Product[F,P]] <: ProductBase
      SomeFactoryGroup[+F <: SomeFactoryGroup[F,P], +P <: SomeProductGroup[F,P]] <: Product[SomeFactoryGroup, SomeProductGroup]
        FooProduct <: SomeProductGroup[FooFactory, FooProduct]
```

You can insert as many levels as you like. We need all of them, including the non-generic `FactoryBase` and `ProductBase`. Though they are not *strictly* necessary as it is possible to get away with existential types, these can get unwieldy. It is easier to say `FactoryBase` than `(SomeFactory | exist F <: Factory[F,P], exist P <: Product[F,P], SomeFactory <: F)` (this is not Scala syntax, deliberately). Sometimes existentials are very useful, but not in this example (perhaps you can use them in other parts of your system). Anyway, these `FactoryBase` objects will be placed in an `Iterable[FactoryBase]` to manage production runs.

Now to maps. There are production runs, during which each factory may produce one instance of a product (or perhaps none). We need, given a factory and a production run, find the product produced by that factory during that run.

One solution is what you have attempted: have production runs represented as (or contain, or whatever) maps from factories to products. Ignoring the types for a moment, in pseudocode:

```
productionrun.lookup(factory) = productionrun.mapFromFactoryToProduct.lookup(factory)
```

This may even work, if we stick to `FactoryBase` and `ProductBase`. But this approach is limiting. A map maps a bunch of things of the type A to a bunch of things of (perhaps different) type B. All keys are type-identical, and all values are type-identical. This is manifestly not what we have. All factories are of different types, and so are all products. We can work around the issue by forgetting part of type information, that is, by storing keys and values reduced to their least-common-denominator type. But what if we need to recover this type information later on? This is impossible to do statically, it is forgotten, lost forever.

The other solution is superficially symmetrical to the first one: have factories represent (or contain, in this case) maps from production runs to products.

```
factory.lookup(productionrun) = factory.mapFromProductionRunToProduct.lookup(productionrun)
```

Production runs in this case are represented just by their unique IDs. But at the type level this solution is very different, and much better, than the first one. All keys in each map are type-identical (they are all, in fact, type-identical, across different factories). All values in each map are type-identical (this type is specific to the factory). There's no type information lost at any stage.

So, to sum up. Have a class `PR` that represents a production run. Create a method `Factory[F,P].findProduct(pr:PR)->Product[F,P]`, implemented by means of `Map[PR, Product[F,P]]`. Have a `makeProduct` method accept a `PR` value, and add the resulting product to the map, keyed by that `PR` value. You can wrap this in a method `PR.lookUpProductByFactory[F,P](f:Factory[F,P])->Product[F,P]` or some such if you want. Also, wrap it in a `FactoryBase.findProduct(pr:PR)->ProductBase`, and wrap *that* into `PR.lookUpProductBaseByFactoryBase(f:FactoryBase)->ProductBase`.

That's it. I hope of these two solutions will suit your needs.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I explicitly don't want indirect lookups, and I was forced to go with simple base classes (i.e. not generic) FactoryBase and ProductBase to work around what appears to be a Scala defficiency: the root of the Foo[+T <: Bar] hierarchy is Foo[Bar], but Scala has no built-in answer for what is the root of Foo[+T <: Foo[T]]. Hope I am wrong.

Comment: Will ask this question separately.